# Is Perl's inet_aton thread-safe?

Tags: perl, multithreading

Is `inet_aton` Thread-Safe?  I know according to UNP that POSIX doesn't require a lot of the Sockets API to be thread safe, and so I have to assume they're not, but in general how do I know if something is thread safe in Perl?  To what extent do I need to lock library function that I call?  And how do I lock them?  When I try something like `lock(&inet_aton)` it gives me an error:  `Can't modify non-lvalue subroutine call in lock`.

And yes, I've read: [Thread-Safety of System Libraries](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlthrtut.html#Thread-Safety-of-System-Libraries)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you read the [`inet_aton` manpage](http://linux.die.net/man/3/inet_aton) carefully you will see that this call does not use any shared state (contrary to the `inet_ntoa` function described in the same manpage), and thus should be thread safe.

That the function writes its result into a caller-provided structure also supports this.

Perl uses [a thin wrapper on top of those functions](http://perldoc.perl.org/Socket.html) and thus doesn't change the thread safety of the underlying library.

Comment: So in general, how do I evaluate thread safety in relation to library calls?  I read this about reentrancy in POSIX: http://www.unix.org/whitepapers/reentrant.html  It seems to indicate static data / state as the main thing to look for.  I guess I just need to check on a func by func basis.  So if I needed for instance to call `inet_ntoa` how could I lock it?

Answer (score 2):

The function `inet_aton` doesn't have any state it keeps between function calls, so I don't see any reason why it wouldn't be thread safe (provided the arguments you pass it aren't shared between threads).

Comment: Usage of global static variables or global external state (e.g. hardware clock), even without statefulness, I believe is a potential issue.